# Es posible modificar las opciones de JSON en html/template?

Tags: json, go

[`html/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) tiene una característica muy conveniente. Si tengo un template así:

```
<html>
...
<script>var x = '{{ .Data }}';</script>
...
</html>
```

La variable `Data` puede ser de cualquier tipo, y `html/template` lo convierte a JSON. Por ejemplo:

```
<html>
...
<script>var x = '{"nombre":"José","edad":32}';</script>
...
</html>
```

Mi pregunta es:  ¿Es posible usar opciones diferentes para el formato de JSON?  Me gustaría, por ejemplo, usar [`json.MarshalIndent()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#MarshalIndent) para hacer la salida del template más fácil leer.

Answer (score 1):

No conozco el lenguaje **go**, nunca lo había visto, pero puedo dar una respuesta que pude desarrollar investigando en internet.

Supongamos este ejemplo, tenemos la siguiente estructura.

```
type keyvalue struct {Nombre, Edad string}
```

Con los siguientes valores.

```
x := []keyvalue{{"José", "32"}}
```

En la siguiente línea se puede ver cómo uso `MarshalIndent`, se pone `\t` para tabular.

```
json, _ := json.MarshalIndent(x, "", "\t")
```

El resultado queda **indentado** de la siguiente manera.

```
[
    {
        "Nombre": "José",
        "Edad": "32"
    }
]
```

Código final.

https://play.golang.org/p/mxWgoopAoJ

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    type keyvalue struct {
        Nombre, Edad string
    }
    x := []keyvalue{{"José", "32"}}
    tr, err := template.New("tr").Parse("{{.}}")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    json, _ := json.MarshalIndent(x, "", "\t")
    err = tr.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "tr", template.HTML(json))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Se pueden utilizar [**Funciones Personalizadas de Plantilla** (*custom template functions*)](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Funcs) para darle el formato deseado.

1. Definimos la función `marshalindent`, que devuelve un [`template.JSStr`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#JSStr) (con escapes válidos dentro de un string de [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)):

   ```golang
   funcMap := template.FuncMap {
       "marshalindent": func(obj interface {}) template.JSStr {
           mi, _ := json.MarshalIndent(obj, "", "    ")
           return template.JSStr(mi)
       },
   }
   ```
2. Usando la función en el template:

   ```golang
   const templ = `<html><body>
   <script>
       var x = '{{ .Data | marshalindent }}';
       console.log(x);
   </script>
   </body></html>`
   ```
3. Y, por último, pasamos la función (en cascada) al renderizador de la plantilla:

   ```golang
   t := template.Must(template.New("").Funcs(funcMap).Parse(templ))
   ```

---

#### Código completo

```golang
import (
    "html/template"
    "encoding/json"
    "os"
)

type Contenido struct {
    Id    int         `json:"Id"`
    Data  Personales  `json:"Data"`
}

type Personales struct {
    Nombre  string  `json:"nombre"`
    Edad    int     `json:"edad"`
}


const templ = `<html><body>
<script>
    var x = '{{ .Data | marshalindent }}';
    console.log(x);
</script>
</body></html>`

func main() {

    funcMap := template.FuncMap {
        "marshalindent": func(obj interface {}) template.JSStr {
            mi, _ := json.MarshalIndent(obj, "", "    ")
            return template.JSStr(mi)
        },
    }

    contenido := Contenido{1, Personales{"José", 32}}

    t := template.Must(template.New("").Funcs(funcMap).Parse(templ))
    if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, contenido); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Demo en Go Playground</kbd>](https://play.golang.org/p/pT9dMhreQy)

#### Resultado

```html
<html><body>
<script>
    var x = '{\n    \x22nombre\x22: \x22José\x22,\n    \x22edad\x22: 32\n}';
    console.log(x);
</script>
</body></html>
```

[<kbd>Demo en Go Playground</kbd>](https://play.golang.org/p/pT9dMhreQy)